Android Dagger hilt classCastException
When I apply obfuscat,
I was able to check the following error.
What should I do?
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application kr.co.test.TestApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: kr.co.test.DaggerTestApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl cannot be cast to kr.co.test.TestApplication_GeneratedInjector
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7672)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2410)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8810)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: kr.co.test.DaggerTestApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl cannot be cast to kr.co.test.TestApplication_GeneratedInjector

I Already use simple_config like this
<ignore-classes>
    
    <class template="class kr.co.test.TestApplication" >
</ignore-classes>

this is my build.gradle
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version")
ksp "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
kspAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
kspTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"


unless there is a reason why you cannot convert to Hilt. if not. i recommend you use Hilt instead of dagger. because, Hilt is build dagger

I don't understand what you mean

Hilt library is built on top of Dagger library. Are you using Dagger to handle Dependency Injection? If so, please switch to using the Hilt library.

He's suggesting you use another library called Hilt that's build on top of Dagger and simplifies some of the management of components and modules.  But seeing as you have hilt in your gradle file you're already doing that.  @NguyễnMạnhCường didn't realize that since Hilt is built on Dagger sometimes it throws the errors you see when it fails to compile.

@GabeSechan i didn't read his question carefully. i didn't read the build.gradle file. so i didn't realize he used Hilt. thanks for explaining it to me

I did what you explained,
I am still experiencing ClassCastException.
I think it's an obfuscation problem, is there a way?
